# How do I delete temp .bed file created by shellfish.py

Tags: python

I am running shellfish.py to perform principal component analsysis. However, I am getting this error below. How do I fix this?

```
17:18:39    Found .bed format data data_WTCCC_f_650.bed
17:18:39    Found binary mapfile data_WTCCC_f_650.bim
17:18:39    shellfish error: Trying to create link to original data file data_WTCCC_f_650.bed, but link file shellfish-temp-16297/848716990677.bed already exists, presumably from a previous shellfish run. Delete any such files before running again.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this file from Python with:

```
import os
os.remove('path/to/bed/file')
```

Of course you can always delete this file by hand. Just find it in the file explorer (or the tool you use) and delete it.

Comment: Thank you. Since I am not familiar with python, do I have to add this to the original shellfish.py script or do it through command line?